# Email Queuing & sending without delay

Tags: c#, .net, windows, scheduled-tasks

I need to fetch some data from DB continuosly without any delay and need to mail by looping through the results from DB.How can I queue emails and send them without time delay.Which is the suggested method to achieve this in .NET?

Comment: Your objectives are still not perfectly clear.  I think "continuously" and "without delay" are what is tripping me up since these terms are physically impossible.  There is always going to be *some* delay.  Why don't you try to explain your workflow in a little more detail.  Being vague in questions is what leads to downvotes and incorrect answers.

Answer (score 1):

you can create a batch file and attach it with a task scheduler in your OS,
also you can call the DB in the page load and save the your table in a data table, after that you can filter on the dt using switch cases, in that case you only go check the DB once in the page load..

Comment: thanks for the reply. How can I continuosly check the DB.I think in task scheduler we can give a minimum of 5 minutes time delay only.

Comment: @G.R your question mentions periodically fetching data from the DB, but now you are checking it continuously?  You might want to edit your question to make your objectives more clear

Comment: i did have the same problem once, i`ve used a batch file to solve it, when you said "periodically" i figure you will access the DB once a day??

Comment: @G.R I`ve added new answer